# Margin hiding link in link behind div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On our website we have a div that holds all the content, then at the top we have an image behind the content div. This div has a slideshow that has images from a plugin. In the back-end i'm adding links and trying to make the slides clickable...

The problem i've got is that for some reason the 350px margin we have above the content box seems to be blocking the link from being clicked.

This is where it's being added:

```
#content.homepage {
margin-top: 350px;
}
```

This is what the slider is adding:

```
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 908px;
```

And this is the style on the link:

```
display: block;
left: 1544px;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100%;
width: 1544px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 99;
opacity: 0;
transition-property: opacity;
transition-duration: 700ms;
transition-timing-function: linear;
```

If you make #content

```
display:none;
```

The link is clickable. If you remove the padding, the link is clickable at the bottom of the page, but behind the margin it seems unclickable?

The link is http://www.applecoredesigns.co.uk

Comment: Can you include some html as well? And just post the full css needed for the bit you are testing. Don't break it up into little bits leaving out the CSS selectors.

Comment: @jerseyetr, he gave you the link to the website. Why would you need some HTML when you have it all?!

Comment: Well for starters, I have no clue what link on the page he is referring to, so I have to comb through your source page to find what you are talking about. Its easier if you just go here https://jsfiddle.net/ and post all the needed code.

Comment: @lonut that was my thinking. I don't know which part of it is causing the error so I showed a few key elements and linked to the site.

Comment: I can't replicate it in a jsfiddle...

Comment: Yes you can. You can do anything on a fiddle you can do on a website pretty much, But since you aren't able to use fiddle, what link is messed up? You just said I have a link messed up, here is my CSS, here is my webpage, find the link im talking about. See why im unable to help?

Comment: @lonut what if in the future the link is broken? Questions and answers maintain their usefulness and relevancy when they are self contained and do not depend on external references to be understood. The website could not exist in a year but the question and answer could remain useful/relevant for years to come if all the necessary parts are include _in post_.

Comment: the purpose of adding html code in here is to make this question independent of any outside links. this site is not only here to help those who ask questions, but to help anyone who may have similar issues and stumble upon your question. if your link ceases to exist and this question is still up, it would render this entire question and solution useless in the future.  also, giving us more details helps us help you find your solution faster. more efficient time use for everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slider itself has a z-index of -1, maybe as part of the original slider's functionality. Changing it to a higher value allows for clicking on each slide.

Comment: I noticed it on the slides but not on the actual slider container! Perfect, thanks!